# supporting multiple languages in cassandra

Tags: utf-8, cassandra, utf, iso-8859-1

I am analyzing Facebook data using Cassandra due to which I ended up having need of multiple languages text in one of my columns.

I am unable to insert text data into Cassandra which is not English:

```
<stdin>:1:'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u010c' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)

<stdin>:1:Invalid syntax at char 7623
```

I browsed thorough the Internet and found that i need to override coding ([link](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HelpOnConfiguration#Configuring_a_single_wiki))
but I am not sure how to configure this.

Note : there is a possibility of multiple language in a single row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your column seems to be of type `ascii`, which only supports US-ASCII-encoded text. If you need a wider range of characters, use `varchar` instead (see [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) for details on CQL types).

To change the column type, use this `ALTER TABLE` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER my_column TYPE varchar;
```

See [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlAlterTable.html) for details on `ALTER TABLE`.